# Generator URL Friendly SEO PHP with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i want to create a URL Friendly with hidden variable, and look like this:

**website.dev/en/page/detail.html** (work, show the content)

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&detail=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

php file:

```
$_GET['lang']); // en
$_GET['page']); // page
$_GET['detail']); // detail.html
```

So, the page return error status 500, but show me the content
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgv5m.png

how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&detail=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not work :(
http://i.imgur.com/ZiAo6Au.png

and with that rule the folder before don't work too

Comment: Check your error.log and paste exact error log you get for the 500 error.

Comment: That means you're not looking at the right file. Every 500 is logged in Apache error.log

Comment: i have find the log file, and is empty with that type of error.
But is solved when change PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.5.24 but why this happen in new version of PHP do you have any ideia?

Comment: This rule is not dependent on any PHP version. Your php 5.6 installation might have got corrupted.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
Your version is better but only work for the long URL
mine work for split URL